# How to make panel height equal in each column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5

In my app i have following, typical for bootstrap view structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

content length inside panel class may be different for each column. Moreover, in one on them part of it is being displayed only when user press a button.

How to ensure that each column will always have the same height? I can setup same column height with use of display: flex as below:

```
.col-md-4 {
    display: flex;
}
```

all 3 columns have same height. But panels not. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `.col-md-4` items have height defined already you can simply add `.h-100` (height: 100%) to panels `class="h-100 panel panel-default"`.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

Answer (score 1):

in bootstrap 4 all columns have display flex & the height of columns is the same. so the content in every column has an effect on another column so if the inside content has full height all of them be the same height.
you need to add h-100 class on content in columns.
like `<div class="h-100 panel panel-default"> </div>`
be attention  this tag should not have vertical margins.